# How to add cron jobs in CloudFoundry

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I have a couple of Python apps in CloudFoundry. Now I would like to schedule their execution. For example a specific app has to be executed on the second day of each month.
I coudldn't find anything on the internet. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Foundry will deploy your application inside a container. You could use libraries to execute your code on a specific schedule but either way you're paying to have that instance run the whole time.

What you're trying to do is a perfect candidate for "[serverless computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing)" (also known as "event-driven" or "function as a service" computing.

These deployment technologies execute functions on response to a trigger e.g. a REST api call, a certain timestamp, a new database insert etc...

You could execute your python cloud foundry apps using the [Openwhisk](http://openwhisk.org/) serverless compute platform.

IBM offer a hosted version of this running on their cloud platform, [Bluemix](http://bluemix.net).

I don't know what your code looks like so I'll use this sample hello world function:

```
import sys

def main(dict):
    if 'message' in dict:
        name = dict['message']
    else:
        name = 'stranger'
    greeting = 'Hello ' + name + '!'
    print(greeting)
    return {'greeting':greeting}
```

You can upload your actions (functions) to OpenWhisk using either the [online editor](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/openwhisk/editor) or the [CLI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/openwhisk/learn/cli).

Once you've uploaded your actions you can automate them on a specific schedule by using the Alarm Package. To do this in the online editor click "automate this process" and pick the alarm package. 
To do this via the CLI we need to first create a trigger:

```
$ wsk trigger create regular_hello_world --feed /whisk.system/alarms/alarm -p cron '0 0 9 * * *'
ok: created trigger feed regular_hello_world
```

This will trigger every day at 9am. We then need to link this trigger to our action by creating a rule:

```
$ wsk rule create regular_hello_rule regular_hello_world hello_world
ok: created rule regular_hello_rule
```

For more info see the [docs on creating python actions.](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#openwhisk_actions_python)

Answer (score 1):

The CloudFoundry platform itself does not have a scheduler (at least not at this time) and the containers where you application runs do not have cron installed (unlikely to ever happen).

If you want to schedule code to periodically run, you have a few options.

- You can deploy an application that includes a scheduler.  The scheduler can run your code directly in that container or it can trigger the code to run elsewhere (ex: it sends an HTTP request to another application and that request triggers the code to run).  If you trigger the code to run elsewhere, you can make the scheduler app run pretty lean (maybe with 64m of memory or less) to reduce costs.
- You can look for a third party scheduler service.  The availability of and cost of services like this will vary depending on your CF provider, but there are service offerings to handle scheduling.  These typically function like the previous example where an HTTP request is sent to your app at a specific time and that triggers your scheduled code.  Many service providers offer free tiers, which give you a small number of triggers per month at no cost.
- If you have a server outside of CF with cron installed, you can use cron there to schedule the tasks and trigger the code to run on CF.  You can do this like the previous examples by sending HTTP requests to your app, however, this option also gives you the possibility to make use of CloudFoundry's task feature.

CloudFoundry has the concept of a task, which is a one-time execution of some code.  With it, you can execute the `cf run-task` command to trigger the task to run.  Ex: `cf run-task <app-name> "python my-task.py"`.  More on that in the docs, [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html).  The nice part about using tasks is that your provider will only bill you while the task is running.

To see if your provider has tasks available, run `cf feature-flags` and look to see if `task_creation` is set to `enabled`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an example for a third party scheduler? Thank you.

Comment: I have used this service on PWS:  https://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/services/temporize.html